# Is slower light darker?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, poynting-vector

Consider for example, electromagnetic waves inside conductors. The speed at which an EM wave travels at can be a considerable fraction lower than C

So my question is, If I were standing with my eyes embedded inside the conductors, facing opposite the wave vector. Would I perceive this light to be darker?

Specifically I am talking about human perception. Which I assume comes from the intensity of light at a specific frequency.

My understanding is that this comes from the poynting vector which is a measure of power flow per unit area HOWEVER the only 2 components of the poynting vector are E and B,

and initially, when t=0 there is NO wave attenuation. Meaning the poynting vector is that same as it was for a vacuum(i think probably not actually). Meaning at T=0 I would assume the poynting vector is the same and thus the same brightness. Yet.. the wave instantly travels slower( yet again I think) and intuitively I would say the light is "darker" as lower transfer of energy

Things I may be overlooking:

I have not studied freznels equations and waves on boundaries  only the EM Wave equation inside a conductor. I am also possibly overlooking the phase difference between the E and B fields when inside the conductor compared to a vacuum at t=0

Please focus on the specific SPEED relation to how "bright or dark" the wave is at t=0, and not due to the attenuation itself, due to work being done on electrons

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is, If I were standing with my eyes embedded inside the conductors, facing opposite the wave vector. Would I perceive this light to be darker?

No. The rate of photons hitting your retina would be unchanged so your perception would be unchanged.

Comment: But isn't the rate at which photons hit my retina dependant on the phase velocity?

Comment: @jensen For a material with zero absorption, photons must enter and exit that material at the same rate.

Comment: And conductors don't absorb light?

Comment: The wave is attenuated because work is being done on electrons

Comment: In terms of the poynting vector  though. What would be the initial poynting vector at t=0,  as the speed is different, thus intuitively I would say that there is a lower intensity

Comment: @jensen I dont understand your question. Any photons you lose you cant see. Any photons you dont lose you can see. It wont matter what the speed of those photons is when they enter your eye.

Comment: What you have said is to do with wave attenuation which is what I'm trying to stay away from. BUT if I lose photons, then the rate at which energy is transfered to my eye decreases thus I would say the light is darker. Which is exactly what the poynting vector predicts would happen as the wave attenuation occurs. The speed of photons, and the number of photons should matter. if I have 10 photons moving at 1m/s or 10 photons move 2m/s I would measure the intensity of light greater for the 2m/s case

Comment: I have not really dealt with the quantum nature of light, so am only really interested in the classical electromagnetic theory. However even in terms of photons, if the photons are moving slower then the rate of energy transfer should surely decrease( even though I'm pretty sure that photons always travel at c in any medium , but atleast the macroscopic group velocity 
of the wave  can be lower)